# how to pass a parsed doccument?

Tags: java, android, parsing, dom, xpath

Hi all and thanks for your time and help.
Im trying to parse a xml file in the "res/raw" folder and passing the result to other class to work with it.
I'm stuck and cannot find any solution, Im trying to learn programming, so, the whole code may be wrong and I failed catastrophically from the beginning.

this is the parser, it get a document from the raw folder and return the parsed document.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import android.app.Activity;

public class Pars extends Activity{

    public Document doc(){

          InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.talechap01);

        Document docout = null;

         DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
          DocumentBuilder builder = null;
        try {
            builder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            docout = builder.parse(is);

        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return docout;
    }
}
```

this class get the parsed document and find some content using xpath and pass it in a return. 
I can not pass the parsed document "docout" from the class "Pars"

```
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpression;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class Commanders {

    public static String getStory(String spage) {

          XPathExpression expr;
          XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

           Object result = null;
           String num = spage;
           String par = null;
           Document doc = //Here I need the document parsed from the "Pars" class

           try {

           expr = xpath.compile("//decision"+num+"/p//text()");

            result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
          }

         catch (XPathExpressionException e) {

             e.printStackTrace();
          }

          NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result;

         for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {

           par = nodes.item(i).getNodeValue();

         //  System.out.println(par);

         }
         return par;
      }
}
```

Here is an example from the xml.
I'm trying to get the content of "

" depending of the "decisionXXX" number.

```
<talechap01>
<Start></Start>
    <decision000 id="000">
        <p> part 1 text</p>
        <p> second row text</p>


        <pick chs= "001" name= "go to decision001"/>
        <pick chs= "002" name= "go to decision002"/>
    </decision000>

    <decision001 id="001">

        <p>parte 2</p>

        <pick chs = "002" name= "go to decision002"/>
        <pick chs = "003" name= "go to decision003"/>

    </decision001>
```

I'm doing something/all wrong?
Is there even possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't understand something, but it seems like attribute "id" is a decision number,
i mean next

> decision000 id=000

If it's true then you can first find nodes which start with and then select by id
I can't check it now, but it should work, try next expression:

```
//*[starts-with(local-name(), 'decision')][@id='your_num_value']
```

Comment: that is not the problem, my problem is I don't know how to pass the parsed document to another class.  Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust the function signature of `Commanders#getStory(java.lang.String)` so it takes your extra `doc` argument. You can then execute your code like...

```
Pars pars = new Pars();

Document doc = pars.doc();
Commanders.getStory(doc, spage)
```

Comment: You mean I have to pass the document to "Commanders" too?
I'm new at this. Could you please be more explanatory and specific?

Comment: Well, if I understand you, you want to access the document in your `getStory` method. As that method is static, then yes you have to pass the document as an argument to that function. I would really suggest that you try and get some basic Java training! There are some tutorials here - http://www.learnjavaonline.org. Particularly relevant to your question would be this section - http://www.learnjavaonline.org/en/Functions

Comment: I tried get the return of "Commanders" from another class in a static and non static way, passing a null document to it with the String:
`public static void main(String[] args){
Commanders c = new Commanders();
Document d = null;
System.out.println(c.getStory("000", d));
//System.out.println(Commanders.getStory("000", d));}`
There is no underline error, but both give this error when I try to run as a java application
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:android/app/Activity..
Thanks a lot. it's getting dificult the autolearning, I haven't someone to explain me.

Comment: I realized and fix the code as you say, passing the document as an argument:
    `Pars p = new Pars();
    Document doc = p.docout();
    System.out.println(Commanders.getStory("000", doc));`

now I'm getting this error:
**bold**"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/app/Activity
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
......at com.test.tests.Test.main(Test.java:12)"**bold**
"Test.java:12" is linked to:"Pars p = new Pars();"
Do I should not try to run it as a java application or the code it still wrong?

Comment: You have defined your `Pars` class as extending the class `Activity`. The error you are seeing is telling you that the class `android.app.Activity` is not available on the classpath. Maybe you need to check which libraries you import.